# Spring Data REST JPA: Integrate automatic CRUD operations with manual controller

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa

I'm using Spring Data REST JPA to build a RESTful web service. So far, Spring is auto-generating all the responses for all the possible methods and for listing all the resources available and even for searches over them:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "scans", path = "scans")
public interface ScanRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Scan, Long> {

List<Scan> findByProjectId(@Param("pid") String pid);
}
```

Now I would like to modify what is returned "only" to POST requests while leaving intact the support to all the others. 
I thought I'd create a controller for this purpose like the following:

```
@Controller
public class ScanController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/scans", method = POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody Result parseScan(@RequestParam String projectId, @RequestParam String tool) {
        return null;
    }
```

However when I do this, the JPA-data auto-generated responses for all the other methods and searches etc. ceases to exist. For instance, I get "Method not allowed" if I forward a GET request.

Besides, how could I access a JSON payload from the controller?

**UPDATE**

Now only one of the exposed resource does back to the default methods for requests not manually handled in my own controller. However I have no idea why it does and why this doesn't happen for any of the other resources.* 
Despite they all only differ in their entity's attributes.

The following particular resource is the one that does back to the default request handlers for anything that is not POST scan/ or GET /scan/// which I declared in the controller:

```
@Controller
public class ScanController {

    @Autowired
    private ScanService scanService;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/scan",
            method = POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    Scan parseScan(@RequestBody Scan rbody) {
                    <...do something...>
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/scans/{id}/{totvuln}/{nth}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    Scan getScan(@PathVariable String id, @PathVariable int totvuln, @PathVariable int nth) throws ScanNotFound {
        <...do something...>
}
```

It has the following repository interface:

```
public interface ScanRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Scan, Long> {}
```

and the following service:

```
@Service
public class ScanServiceImpl implements ScanService {

    @Resource
    private ScanRepository scanRepository;

    @Resource
    private ResultRepository resultRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Scan create(Scan shop) {
        <some code>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Scan findById(long id) {
        <some code>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = ScanNotFound.class)
    public Scan delete(long id) throws ScanNotFound {
                    <some code>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Scan> findAll() {
                    <some code>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = ScanNotFound.class)
    public Scan update(Scan scan) throws ScanNotFound {
                    <some code>
    }
}
```

and the resource itself has the following attributes:

```
@Entity
public class Scan {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long projectId;

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Result> result;

    private int totV;

    <getters and setters>
}
```

While the following semi-identical resource "Rules" does not back to any of the default request handlers. It returns "Method not Allowed" for anything different from POST /rule:

```
@Controller
public class RulesController {

    @Autowired
    private RulesService rService;

    @Resource
    private ScanRepository scanRepository;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/rule",
            method = POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    Rules generateRules(@RequestBody Scan rbody) throws Exception {
       <do something>
    }
}
```

It has the same repository interface:

```
public interface RulesRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Rules, Long> {}
```

and also the same service implementation:

```
@Service
public class RulesServiceImpl implements RulesService {

    @Resource
    private RulesRepository rRepository;

    @Resource
    private ResultRepository resultRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Rules create(Rules shop) {        
        <do something>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Rules findById(long id) {
        <do something>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = RulesNotFound.class)
    public Rules delete(long id) throws RulesNotFound {
                <do something>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Rules> findAll() {
        <do something>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Rules findByScanId(long id) throws RulesNotFound {
        <do something>
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = RulesNotFound.class)
    public Rules update(Rules scan) throws RulesNotFound {
        <do something>
    }
}
```

and the resource Rules itself has the following attributes:

```
@Entity
public class Rules {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Scan scan;

    @OneToMany
    private Collection<Result> result;

    private String rules;

    <getters and setters>
}
```

Why isn't Spring exposing the default request handlers also for "Rules" for any request that hasn't been specified manually in my controller class?

I would truly appreciate if you could point out why. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to access a JSON payload from the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/scan",
            method = POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    Scan parseScan(@RequestBody Scan rbody) {
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.setProjectId(rbody.getProjectId());
        scan.setTool(rbody.getTool());
        return scan;
    }
```

Also I've realised the automatic CRUD operations were actually being already supported for every request not handled by my own controller: I was just requesting the wrong URL.
I got the list of correct URLs to use by requesting "curl http://localhost:8080"

However, the preferred URL for any of the auto-generated operations can be set with

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = pref_URL_suffix, path = pref_URL_suffix)
```

^^somehow during all the changes I tried, that line above went missing.